# Advice on scaling and optimizing an API endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, architecture, multiprocessing

I am looking for advice on how to optimize an existing API endpoint to scale better and run faster. I have written an endpoint with some multiprocessing, which takes in a user-specified search term and does the following:

1. Send a request to a third-party API with the search term.
2. Receive the results from the third-party API (about 50,000 - 100,000 JSON objects stored in an array).
3. Split up the results across 4 workers.
4. Run all 4 workers simultaneously to transform the results.

   4a. Each worker may need to make additional calls to the third-party API during the transformation process (~400 additional API calls across all the workers)
5. Combine the processed results into a JSON object and return the results.

Currently, this endpoint can take from 10s to 1 minute to execute. Additionally, if more than two requests are made to this endpoint at the same time, the machine will run out of resources and fail when attempting to transform the results. This endpoint is hosted on a single EC2 instance.

I have looked into adopting an architecture similar to MapReduce with each worker running on it's own machine. Also, one of my peers suggested using AWS Lambda, however, I am not familiar with the service. This endpoint operates within a web app, however, the web app simply makes a request to the endpoint. Therefore, the architecture and hosting of this specific endpoint is flexible. Any advice on what a typical solution to this problem would be? Even just some direction on what topics I should look into would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this process have to be synchronous?  How many requests like this do you expect at the same time?

Comment: The process does not necessarily have to be synchronous, but the results of the 3rd-party API cannot be stored/cached due to their ToS. I have thought about using pagination, but it becomes tricky with the 3rd-party API. At this time, I wouldn't expect more than 10-20 requests at the same time. However, I would like to build an architecture that can scale relatively easily, if need be.

Comment: There are lots of different options. Since you mentioned lambda: If you can do the work async: write the request data to a random ID s3 file, return the ID to the client and end the request. The client can then poll using that ID. On the server you'd just return the s3 file for polling. Now listen to s3 writes with aws lambda and do the work (you could spawn multiple lambda functions and get really technical, but just using one for now should be fine). Once work is completed, write to the s3 file. Gives you a nice and clean separation between the request and the worker

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. I will look more into leveraging Lambda.